# Rearrange Lists of Rows in One Spot Based on Chronological Order of Dates in Those Rows

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2016

I have four courses that I want to plan this term. I listed each course's data of tests and assignments in separate tables in excel as following:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/DZz8Wl.png]

I want to solve the problem of compiling and reordering the rows of these tables based on chronological order of their dates in different and single spot as following:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/CXE4Ul.png]

Whether using of Formulas, Conditional Formatting or somethings else, what is the most efficient method to do this?

Comment: Copy all the data (in it's current order) to it's new location. Then select all the data and sort it by the dates column in ascending order. Choose Sort... from the Data menu, and specify the sort column and order.

Answer (score 0):

*After considering the Data Ranges for different Courses and the Final Output, I can suggest you to do the followings.*

1. Collect all 4 parts in one Data Range either by Copy & Paste or VBA Code.
2. Sort the Entire Range on Date in Ascending order.
3. Finally apply the Conditional Formatting.

*You can use this simple VBA code to Copy & Paste Data along with Cell Formats will save your time and you can skip the Format.*

```
Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim CopyRng As Range, PasteRng As Range

Title = "Copy & Paste"

Set CopyRng = Application.Selection

  Set CopyRng = Application.InputBox("Ranges to Copy :", Title, CopyRng.Address, Type:=8)
    Set PasteRng = Application.InputBox("Range to Paste, select Single cell):", Title, Type:=8)

       CopyRng.Copy

         PasteRng.Parent.Activate

           PasteRng.PasteSpecial xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats

            PasteRng.PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats

         Application.CutCopyMode = False

End Sub
```

*This VBA Code you can use to Sort on Date column.*

```
Sub CommandButton2_Click()

Dim SortRange As Range, keyRange As Range

  Set SortRange = Application.InputBox("Sort Range", SortRange.Address,Type:=8)

  Set keyRange = Application.InputBox("Key Range", keyRange.Address,Type:=8) 

SortRange.Sort Key1:=keyRange, Order1:=xlAscending

End Sub
```

**NB:** *Hope this help you. If my solution differs from your idea just drop comment.*